# Google OAuth2 with Google Cloud Storage Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

I am trying to authenticate into google cloud storage using a java app. I can already get a token using OAuth 2 with google. I have tried to research but can't seem to find any answers.

**Resolved**

Comment: Please, if you say that you have solved, edit back the original post, and tell us in an answer how you solved it, for future reference of the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically all I had to do was add the scopes in the Java class instead of inside the JSON file. Was looking at the wrong place. Attaching it with code snippet below

```
/** OAuth 2.0 scopes. */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform");
```